# Accessing browser events in chrome extension - DOM events in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome plugin in which I would like to receive events such as "load", "unload" of window and page. However, I'm not getting any concrete clue to start with.

Can anyone tell me how to capture DOM event in plugin?

Does Chrome support this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and you just add normal browser events to the JavaScript you inject as you stated in your question. Every page will have that content script and it will listen on those events.

Comment: i was searching for dom events in chrome extension and ended up here with a favorable answer. :)